# Add new line of text to multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, user-interface

<del>I am looking for a tool/shell command to edit multiple files. My exact use case is search recursively for a config files with a particular name and add a new line of config to it.</del>

Rewording:
I have a bunch of configs in several dirs:

```
For ex:
/Users/myth/app1/config/a.cfg
/Users/myth/app1/config/b.cfg

/Users/myth/app2/config/a.cfg
/Users/myth/app2/config/b.cfg

/Users/myth/app3/config/a.cfg
/Users/myth/app3/config/b.cfg

/Users/myth/app4/config/a.cfg
/Users/myth/app4/config/b.cfg
```

I have to insert a line of configuration only in the a.cfg of all apps. I can find all the configs with `find . -name "a.cfg"`. Now how would I pipe that to something like an echo or tee to just append a line of config on the last line of all a.cfg? I cannot use a shared a.cfg for these apps because content of a.cfg is not the same for all apps. But this line I intend to add is the same.

**Update:** 
This is what I ended up using:

```
for configFile in $(find /Users/myth -type f -name "a.cfg" | xargs grep -iL "new config")
do
    echo "new config" >> $configFile
done
```

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. I've reworded my q. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo >> `find /start/directory -name "a.cfg"`
```

Echo should add append a new line to a list of paths listed by find command. Backtick enrures the "right" part of the command happens first.